# Восстановление файла в debugfs

Tags: linux, ext4

Почему, когда я удаляю файл в ext4, а затем восстанавливаю его через debugfs, - он не восстанавливается видимым образом?

Последовательность действий:

```
$ sudo debugfs -w /dev/sda7
debugfs: ls
145312 (12) . 140473 (28) .. 145313 (16) file.one
debugfs: rm file.one
debugfs: ls
145312 (12) . 140473 (28) ..
debugfs: stat <145313>
#...
dtime: 0x56788cb4
#...
debugfs: undel <145313>
debugfs: stat <145313>
#... (НЕТ dtime, все как обычно)
debugfs: ls
145312 (12) . 140473 (28) ..
```

Выходит так, что после удаления инод числится как удаленный, потом я восстанавливаю его, он выглядит как обычный, но файла на прежнем месте не появляется. Что я забыл?

Comment: Никогда не разбирался с debugfs, просто замечу, что инод и запись в каталоге это разные вещи. например инод не хранит имени файла. подозреваю, что помимо восстановления инода надо воссоздать запись каталога, которая по сути является ссылкой на инод.

Comment: не, в каталоге есть запись о файле. если посмотреть ls -d или еще как-то. и инод есть, и запись есть, а вот между собой они не связаны... надо поискать.

Answer (score 1):

Да, чтобы действительно восстановить файл, нужно сделать undel <145313> file.restored, а не просто undel <145313>, но это не решает проблемы понимания, что конкретно делается в момент исполнения этой команды.
Я уж пробовал по отдельности все вместе, там говорилось, что: для восстановления файла нужно удалить время удаления (DTIME), увеличить количество ссылок с 0 на 1 (но оно практически всегда и так остается равным 1), затем я еще пробовал вручную ставить флаг IN-USE для инода, проверял запись в каталоге - запись после удаления файла о нем остается (название файла), но после восстановления инода он не появляется в каталоге как соответствующий файл... В общем неясно.